# what's the best way to save settings for different jquery plugin instances among methods?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a simple jquery plugin. I init my plugin with some settings, say `{persistent: 'new'}`.
Later when I want to update the settings for my plugin, how can I access the existing settings?

I do not want to change the defaults for other instances though.

I'm thinking about saving options to somewhere like `data('options')`, but is there a more conventional way to do it?

```
(function() {

    var defaults = {
        persistent : 'old'
    };

    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {

            options = $.extend(defaults, {}, options);

            return this.each(function(n) {

            });

        },

        update: function(options) {

            // how to access the options in init?
            options = $.extend(defaults, {}, options);

            return this.each(function(n) {

            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.updatable = function(method) {

        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.updatable');
        }

    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Why not use HTML5 storage? http://html5.litten.com/html5-web-storage-using-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-objects/

Comment: @Chris I don't thinks that's better option than $.data(). Actually it seems make no sense to use localStorage for jquery plugin options.